# How do I use the RemoveAtWords function in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to remove various words from a text field in MS Access.

The data might look like:

> Can somebody tell me how I can use you Function to remove Word "NONE" in a long string of word ex. str = Me.Combo1.Column(2) & Me.Combo2.Column(2) ect.

```vb
Public Function RemoveAtWords(strOriginal As String) As String

Dim strParts() As String
Dim i As Integer

strParts() = Split(strOriginal, " ")

For i = LBound(strParts) To UBound(strParts)
    If Left(strParts(i), 1) <> "NONE" Then
        RemoveAtWords = RemoveAtWords & "" & strParts(i)
    End If
Next

RemoveAtWords = Trim(RemoveAtWords)

End Function
```

I integrated into a private Sub to copy it to the clipboard.

```vb
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Me.Text1.SetFocus
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all the NONE occurrences in your string a simple replace will do.

Something like that:

```
    Private Sub Command1_Click()
   test1 "Can somebody tell me how I can use you Function to remove Word NONE"
End Sub

Private Function test1(a As String)
   
   If InStr(a, "NONE") > 0 Then
      MsgBox "Original: " & a & vbCrLf & "Adjusted: " & Replace(a, "NONE", "")
   End If
End Function
```

Comment: This will replace any occurrence of "NONE" (for example "NONENTITY" will become "NTITY") rather than any instance of the word "NONE". Using `Replace(strData," NONE "," ")` will deal with whole words. You may have problems where punctuation exists, such as "Answer there came none."

Comment: Thanks. Is it also possible to run the Public Function on:                                                
 Private Sub UpdateSKU()
    Dim str As String str = Me.Combo216.Column(1) & Space(1) & Me.Combo224.Column(1) & Space(1)  etc. and so on.                                 
 Me.Text423.Value = str                               I want to remove text "NONE" in the text line.                           a BIG thanks you for you help.